# What is the difference between AWS Workspaces and a RDP enabled EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS Workspaces provide RDP machines but are more costly compared to EC2 instances. Also the control is less than what we can achieve running EC2 instances on the cloud. Are there any advantages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon WorkSpaces support Windows 10.

EC2 does not support Windows 7/8/10 except on Dedicated Hosts and Dedicated Instances and you must provide your own licenses (BYOL). EC2 only supports Windows Server versions otherwise.

Comment: AWS WorkSpaces have the Windows 10 experience, but is powered by Windows Server 2016. Only if organizations can bring their own Windows Desktop licenses, you can run Windows 10 Enterprise edition on your WorkSpaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think EC2 is best for the development of applications. see [What is Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html)

[AWS Workspaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/), on the other hand, is a manged multi-purpose desktop as a service offering like [V2 Cloud's WorkSpaces](https://www.v2cloud.com/cloud-workspaces/)

Answer (score 0):

WorkSpaces provides a PCoIP protocol optimized for desktop experience. EC2 does not.

ref:

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6c8jdm/ec2_equivalent_of_aws_standard_workspace/dhtdt36?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

http://www.teradici.com/what-is-pcoip/pcoip-ultra